# Generating a short, pseudo-random verifiable alpha numeric code

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random, token

I have a situation where I need to generate short pseudo-random alphanumeric tokens which are unique, verifiable, and easily type-able by a human. These will be generated from a web app. The tokens don't need to be highly secure - they're used in a silly web game to claim a silly prize. For various reasons, the client wants these tokens to be human-readable and handled via email. This is non-negotiable (I know... but this is how it has to be for reasons beyond my control).

In other words, let's say we get the code "ABCDE12345"

- There has to be a way to say "ABCDE12345" is "valid". For example: maybe two or three characters at the start run through an algorithm I write will generate the right sequence of remaining characters. E.g., `f("AB")==="CDE12345"`
- Two people playing the game shouldn't be likely to generate the same token. In my mind, I'd be happy to use the current time in millis + game-character name & score to seed a home-made RNG. (which is to say, NOT use Math.random, since this is a web app). This would seed the two or three character sequence mentioned above.

Am I missing anything? I'm not looking for a concrete algorithm but rather your suggestions. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: I am assuming the game is stateless, when it comes to the codes? (i.e. it cannot store the known generated codes)?

Comment: The game is stateless in the server sense. That being said, it uses localStorage to keep character, score etc on the player's device.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: I did! But this was 5 years and 2 jobs ago... I don’t recall how exactly I ended up solving it other than that the discussion here led me down a good path.

Answer (score 1):

If you think your token is comparable to an authenticated message saying "give this person a prize" you could look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code, recoding as necessary with e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 to make the thing printable. Of course, HMAC uses a secret key which you will have to KEEP secret. A public key signature system would not require that you keep the key secret, but I would expect the signature to be longer, and I expect that it is already too long for you if you want non-trivial security.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (and easy to hack) would be to generate a meaningful term (one way to achieve such is choose a random article from wikipedia), [encrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) it with a pre-known password, and take the least significant x bits.

Now, the key you generate is `word-<x bits as a number>`.

This is easily verifiable by machine, simply re-encode the word and check if the bits fit, and offers a simple tradeoff of readability vs security (bigger x -> less readable, harder to fake).

Main problem with this approach though, is assuming your game is not communicating with any server, you will need to deploy the preshared secret somehow to your clients, and they will be able to reverse engineer it.